# WGCNA requires always trait data?

Tags: r

I did RNA-seq analysis and I'm planning to analyze with WGCNA, I have seen several papers with trait data, but I have a large RNA-seq sampling but few trait data. I was wondering if it is valid do WGCNA just with the expression data and not including any trait data.

Comment: AFAIK, The trait data are not used at every step. They are used only when you want to determine whether some of the identified gene modules are related to the trait. You can always identified co expressed gene modules wihout trait data. and biostar is a better choice for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WGCNA can definitely be used without corresponding trait data. In fact, using trait data (to relate modules to possible functional aspects) comes after network construction, and is a separate step.

You also don't have to just relate your modules to trait data specifically. You can also look at defining your modules based on geneset enrichment analyses and the like.